# Json content using Jquery and Mustache - wamp

Tags: jquery, json, wamp, mustache

I have an HTML file with a MUSTACHE template + JSON file in my wamp server.
I want to fill my HTML with content of JSON.
Why is it now working?

**.HTML**

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>Mustache Sample</title>
    </head>


    <body>
        <div id="speakerbox">
            <div id="carousel"></div>
        </div>

    <!--template-->
    <script id="speakerstpl" type="text/template">
        {{#speakers}}
            <div class="speakers">
                <h3>{{shortname}}</h3>
            </div>
        {{/speakers}}
    </script>

    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mustache.js/0.8.1/mustache.min.js"></script>


    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function(){
            $.getJSON('data.json', function (data){
                    var template = $('#speakerstpl').html();
                    var html = Mustache.to_html(template, data);
                    $('#carousel').html(html);
            }); //get json
        });//function
    </script>    

    </body>
    </html>
```

**.JSON**

```
[
  {
    "speakers": [
      {
        "name": "ana", 
        "shortname": "ann",
        "bio": "biogg"
      }, 
      {
        "name": "bolacha", 
        "shortname": "bol",
        "bio": "biogg de bolacha"
      }
     ]
  }
]
```

Is there a problem with Json?

I am missing something in HTML?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: What do you mean "not working"?  What error message or results are you getting?  What have you tried?  This information will all help people answer your question.  As it stands, it is very difficult to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is you have `speakers` enclosed in an array which means you need to use `data[0]` as your argument to `to_html` ([fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/z6u2d5jf/)):

```
   $(function(){
        $.getJSON('data.json', function (data){
                var template = $('#speakerstpl').html();
                var html = Mustache.to_html(template, data[0]);
                $('#carousel').html(html);
        }); //get json
    });//function
```

Alternatively you could remove the enclosing array in which case your json would look like ([fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/z6u2d5jf/1/)):

```
{
    "speakers": [
      {
        "name": "ana", 
        "shortname": "ann",
        "bio": "biogg"
      }, 
      {
        "name": "bolacha", 
        "shortname": "bol",
        "bio": "biogg de bolacha"
      }
     ]
  }
```